# What is the subject line in HTML?

Tags: html

A host company sent this Client Template, containing some directions. But I didn't understand this paragraph:

> To avoid being flagged as spam, do not using the following elements in the subject line: &, ?, !, capital letters, repetitions of the same word, numbers, percentage marks at the beginning or the end of the title.

Comment: seems more to do with the mailto - when you do a email from a link you do <a href="mailto:user@domain?subject=whateverthesubjectis">email</a>

Comment: This is referring to HTML email newsletters

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't have a subject line, but e-mails do and they probably mean that if your website sends out anything you need to follow those guidelines to avoid it being flagged as spam.